# Return ' MATCH ' if cells contain equal value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database with different names for the same phone number. But some of the mobile numbers contains same names as listed below. So I have to Match mobile numbers having same names as shown in the below pic. Ignore blank cells. Its a large database, so number of columns and rows may vary. Please find a solution for this issue. In the below sheet B2 and C2 are different, so F2 should be 'MISMATCH'. B3,C3 and D3 are equal then f3 should be 'MATCH' and so on.    PFA[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` and `reduce()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  mob, A2:A, 
  name1, B2:B, 
  rest_, lambda(c, offset(c, 0, 1, 1, columns(C2:E))), 
  map(mob, name1, lambda(m, n, 
    ifs( 
      m = "", 
        iferror(ø), 
      reduce(true, rest_(n), lambda(b, r, and(b, or(r = "", r = n)))), 
        "match", 
      true, 
        "mismatch"         
    ) 
  )) 
)
```

See [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) and [reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597).